# Recognize text in images with ML Kit on Android on device offline

Tags: android, ocr, google-mlkit

Google at: [Recognize text on device](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android) says:

> Optional but recommended: You can configure your app to automatically download the ML model to the device after your app is installed from the Play Store. To do so, add the following declaration to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file:

> If you do not enable install-time model downloads, the model will be downloaded the first time you run the on-device detector. Requests you make before the download has completed will produce no results.

Why cannot I recognize text when in airplane mode"?

Regards,
Meir

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** You need an Internet connection after installing the app to be able to download the models

---

If you are installing the app while the device is in airplane mode, then the ML Kit SDK will not be able to download the model. You have to install it with some Internet connection, then disable it after a while, and the app should be able to recognize text.

Comment: It didn't work. I did wait for about 10 minutes, then run one recognition while online. then switched to Airplane mode, and it didn't work

Comment: Once the model get downloaded, it should work the same with/without internet. If it still doesn't work for you, could you run the steps to reproduce this issue, grab a bugreport(get it by $adb bugreport) and file a bug here(https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=897785&template=1457144) so that we can check what happened?